# Google search console reports gymweb.it malware detected, but I can't find any trace of it on my site

Tags: google, malware, blacklist, virus

I have a site that keeps getting flagged by Google as containing malware of some sort. Report [here](https://www.google.com/transparencyreport/safebrowsing/diagnostic/index.html?hl=en-US#url=http://joshuaellis.co.uk/)

We've used a site ripper and downloaded the HTML/Images/CSS/JS and then searched for the term gymweb.it and there are no traces of this. Has anyone ever had this problem before relating to gymweb.it and do you have any recommendations/advice on what else i can do?

Comment: Is it wordpress or other CMS?  I'd be looking at plugins, javascript etc.  You may not see that search string because it may not be in clear text.

Also the site referred to in the report doesn't exist in DNS, so we can't even look at it.

Comment: Have you used "Fetch as Google" to see your site?   Some hacks are designed to only feed keywords to Googlbot and not to your own crawler.

Comment: As well, consider if you are on shared hosting, it is possible that one infection within another web space can infect your site. Also consider, that mistakes are made. Some anti-virus systems feed black-lists and Google checks these black-lists. It is not uncommon for an anti-virus to have a false hit against JavaScript.

Comment: thank you for you're suggestions, will do some more digging around and checks.

Comment: I'm not sure what web server you are using, but check configuration files to make sure that certain URLs aren't being redirected to other URLs based on IP addresses.

Comment: Are you linking to any third party scripts, images, advertising networks etc - any links to off-site resources can inject malware into the page served to your visitors without there being anything malicious on your site itself.

Answer (score 1):

I have looked into the history of gymweb.it and it looks rather sketchy, perhaps its a site that has not been maintained and has fallen into some sort of typical botnet type injection.

Download all files directly from the server and do a recursive search through all of them for the term "gymweb".

Rip your database and do a search through that too as you may find it there.

Its also worth noting that your hosting provider may have rectified the issue and Google has not picked up on the fix yet as in my experience it can take a day or more.